# Threaded Sub-Procedure Within A Module Not Obtaining Correct Data From Other Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, threadpool

I have an ArrayList that is set to Friend. Once I click my button "abc" is added to the ArrayList and then the form MsgBoxes out the Count of 1 (Correct).

When I use Threadpool to count the number of objects within the ArrayList it always returns 0.

Example:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Friend Alphabet As New ArrayList

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Alphabet.Add("abc")
        MessageBox.Show("Main Sub: " & Alphabet.Count().ToString())
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TestIt))
    End Sub

End Class

Module MyModule
    Public Sub TestIt()
        MessageBox.Show("Threaded Sub: " & Form1.Alphabet.Count().ToString())
    End Sub
End Module
```

I am obviously getting some sort of cross-thread issue here but have no idea how to correct this. I usually just setup single threads so this is my first time playing with ThreadPool & already lost at step 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [QueueUseWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx) you can pass in an object. Then your method will have one paramter only of type object. This will allow you to send the object at the time of the event since the Thread could run at anytime.

Comment: I am actually running multiple threads that need to access the same arraylist which is why I wanted to have just 1 ArrayList which multiple threads will be using then Synclocking on execution to set to inuse so each item is not used by multiple threads.

Comment: Well you still can pass by Ref or Value depending on what you need. Otherwise then you need to implement a locking mechanism. But based on your current code then you can pass in an object. So in order to better help you, what will the Threads do exactly?

Comment: Ahh gd idea, didn't think about that. I am passing in an ArrayList of 100 links - ArrayList.Add({Link,Status,Inuse}). Each thread then goes to the site & checks for Follow/No-Follow backlinks. At the start of the process it will set Inuse to True so that other threads do not use it then when there are none left it will complete. I wanted to use ThreadPool as a start to learning it + I will have some other Subs I want to run to access the same list at the same time but only for ones that it has already checked :)

Comment: Also, how exactly would you add the object into the call?

Comment: So you can keep list in the form but pass the data to the thread for the the list. Then the object pass by ref of the value and you can update it that you. You may need to mark the Inuse volatile to make sure you don't run into issue, or provide proper locking mechanisms.

Comment: @Chris after you create you wait handle put ", [object to pass]" and then Public Sub TestIt(object data).

Comment: Sorry Brad, I'm a bit confused with your last message, did you mean like this: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TestIt, Alphabet)). I understand the Public Sub TestIt(ByRef Alphabet As ArrayList) part!

Comment: Nope - ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf TestIt), Alphabet) -- See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx.  Also it HAS to be type Object.

Comment: After copying the example it will only allow me to pass the reference Byval, it will not allow ByRef, I'll give up and try something else for the minute, spent too long playing with this now!